# Ansible - retry failed iterations in a loop

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a list of entities that I need to remove, but if I iterate the loop too quickly, the removal may fail as the operation can only be done serially and needs approx 10 seconds between removals. So, I am doing this

```
- name:  Loop through removing all hosts
  shell: "echo yes | gravity remove --force {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
  loop_control:
    pause: 12
```

this generally works fine, but very occasionally I may get an error when the 12 seconds is not enough. I don't want to increase the pause, so am trying to figure out how to test and retry any failures.

A simple additional pause and retry again if an individual node fails would work. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Duh! I had originally tried an until, but stupidly forgot to register the var, so it wasn't working, but this now works

```
- name:  Loop through removing all hosts
  shell: "echo yes | gravity remove --force {{ item }}"
  register: result
  loop: "{{ file_list.stdout_lines }}"
  loop_control:
    pause: 12
  retries: 2
  delay: 12
  until: result is not failed
```